# Store vuex Cannot read property 'store' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I tried to create a first simple App but I have a problem with store.

I have in mainJS

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

Vue.use(Vuex);


import {store} from './Store.js';
store.commit('increment')

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
   store,
  template: '<div><App></App></div>',
  components: { App }
});
```

So in my **store.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        count: 0
    },
    mutations: {
        increment (state) {
            state.count++
        }
    }
});
```

So I would create a child component of App Component that use a event **increment**, so I have created a Component **Counter**

```
<template>
    <div>{{ count }}</div>
</template>
<script>

export default {

    name: "Counter",
    computed: {
        count () {
            return this.$.store.state.count
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

And I call this component from my App component that it is:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img src="./assets/logo.png">
    <router-view/>
    <Counter></Counter>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Counter from './components/Counter.vue'
export default {
  name: 'app',
  components:{
      Counter
  }
}
</script>
```

But I have this error in my **Counter**  component:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'store'
>   of undefined"
>
> found in
>
> --->  at src\components\Counter.vue
>           at src\App.vue

Comment: Try `this.$store.state.count` instead of `this.$.store.state.count` (Remove the `.` after the `$`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You only made a small mistake: It has to be `$store`, not `$.store`:

```
<template>
    <div>{{ count }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "Counter",
    computed: {
        count () {
            return this.$store.state.count
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and changing from `Vue` to `vue` and `Vuex` to `vuex` in all lines of .js store file I got it working.